# RXJS versions mismatch while installing new dependencies in npm

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I've a recurrent problem with **rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12** and **rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6** versions. When I try to install new npm libraries the console shows me this error:

```
MacBook:angular2-seed$ npm install less
angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 /Volumes/Data/Proyectos/Paytime/angular2-seed
├─┬ less@2.7.1 
│ ├─┬ errno@0.1.4 
│ │ └── prr@0.0.0 
│ ├── image-size@0.5.0 
│ ├── mime@1.3.4 
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│ ├─┬ promise@7.1.1 
│ │ └── asap@2.0.5 
│ └── source-map@0.5.6 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6

npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Then, If I change the version of rxjs I get this other error:

```
MacBook:angular2-seed$ npm install

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall /Volumes/Data/Proyectos/Paytime/angular2-seed
> typings install


└── es6-shim (ambient)

angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 /Volumes/Data/Proyectos/Paytime/angular2-seed
└─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
  └── symbol-observable@1.0.2 

npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code 1
MacBook:angular2-seed$
```

I'm in a continuous loop and I don't know how to resolve it, could you help me please?

My package.json content is:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove `"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17"` from your `dependencies`. That is completely outdated and no longer used.

Angular 2.0.x base dependencies are as follow:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

If you are following Angular 2 quickstart example, you can clone it again from the github repo: https://github.com/angular/quickstart